# Zend Framework: How to POST data to some external page (e.g. external payment gate) without using form?

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, payment-gateway

I would like to have a user redirected to an external credit card gate. Of course I have to POST some user info to that gate, but I don't know how exactly can I do this.

I know that I could do this by generating a html form with hidden or read-only fields and have a user click "Submit" button. But this solution is not perfect, because all the form data could be easily changed using e.g. Firebug. I think you cannot do this using $this->_redirect(...). But maybe there is some other solution?

Many thanks for any tips or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to have a user redirected to an external credit card gate. Of course I have to POST some user info to that gate, but I don't know how exactly can I do this.

Using a form is the only method available. The RFC states that the user should explicitly agree to sending a POST (i.e. click on a submit button).

> I know that I could do this by generating a html form with hidden or read-only fields and have a user click "Submit" button. But this solution is not perfect, because all the form data could be easily changed using e.g.

It is no more secure that using a redirect as the header data can be modified without too much of a problem. There are even Firefox plugins to do it.

Comment: Thanks. So it appears that I have to go with a form.

Answer (score 1):

use cURL to post data

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.adapters.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: This will not allow you to redirect the user to the payment gateway.

Comment: depends on if you want to redirect. his question was merely to post data. short of creating a you're own form, you send data via a post request with cURL